# unable to create lldb private: Xcode can't run the app on iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

After I changed something on the project settings all of sudden,
I am getting `"unable to create lldb private"`error and xcode can't run the app on my iphone
Any idea please?

Comment: Is that the entire message? There must be a lot more.

Comment: Add screen shot please

Comment: Your question is fairly vague "After I changed something" - what specifically have you changed if you can recall? Screen shot your build settings and post it please.

Comment: I had this problem. Not actually sure how I fixed it but I did open 'Edit Scheme' (click your app name, top left). In the Run section, my executable was missing to I added it back in. Then under Test, I choose LLDB as the Debugger.

Answer (score 2):

[**Error Pic:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpSoi.png)

[image]

**Solution** :

```
 Goto : Targets > Build settings > Linking -> Mach-O Type = Executable
```