# Xcode iOS app crash on launch: unable to create lldb_private::Process

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I've been trying to get my OpenFL game to build for days, and finally got to the point where the build succeeds (had a lot of trouble linking everything correctly, using severla static libraries of different shapes and forms). It finally builds, and now I Get this:

How can I debug this? In the console it just says

> error: failed to launch
>   '/Users/joon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TryHarder-cynkhfxgstydmgawfivgqqiluryl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TryHarder.app/TryHarder'
>   -- unable to create lldb_private::Process

I have rebooted computer, mobilde device, cleaned, rebuilt, uninstalled, which is what many sources recommend in the case of an on-launch crash with no info. Nothing does the trick however. Some sources recommend to set debugger to GDB, which is no longer possible in XCode 6 it seems.

I'm not sure how to debug this any further.

[image]

Comment: [Goto for Ans :](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33167336/2775981) **://stackoverflow.com/a/33167336/2775981**

Answer (score 0):

I began to get this when I changed Mach-O type to "Bundle" in Targets > build settings > Linking. I won't claim to know much about this, but perhaps it will help..

Answer (score 0):

Set the **Mach-O** type to **Executable** and it will work absolutely fine. you can find it in **Targets > build settings > Linking**